# How to use the IMutableEntityType AddForeignKey() function

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In my EF Core 5 project I use a polymorphic base class for many entities in different databases, thus I need to manually add foreign keys

```
    public abstract class TrackedEntity
    {
        public DateTimeOffset LastUpdated { get; set; }
        public Guid LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }
        //...
    }
```

Currently I do this for each entity as in

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<DashboardTemplate>()
                    .HasOne<User>()
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(tracked => tracked.LastUpdatedBy);
```

I recently came across Jon P Smith's excellent little library EfCore.SoftDeleteServices [http://mng.bz/op7r] that gave me the idea that I could considerably tidy this up, by automating with something like

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            if (typeof(TrackedEntity).IsAssignableFrom(entityType.ClrType))
            {
                entityType.AddForeignKey(...);
            }
        }
```

Unfortunately I cannot find any documentation on how I would go about calling AddForeignKey()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`AddForeignKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.imutableentitytype.addforeignkey?view=efcore-5.0) method expects 3 arguments (all in terms of EF Core metadata) - the property (or properties) of the dependent entity type defining the foreign key and the principal entity key and type.

In your case, first is the `LastUpdatedBy` property of the entity and next are the `User` entity primary key and type. So the usage would be something like this:

```cs
var principalEntityType = modelBuilder.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(User));
var principalKey = principalEntityType.FindPrimaryKey();
foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
    if (typeof(TrackedEntity).IsAssignableFrom(entityType.ClrType))
    {
        var property = entityType.FindProperty(nameof(TrackedEntity.LastUpdatedBy));
        entityType.AddForeignKey(property, principalKey, principalEntityType);
    }
}
```